# How can I catch return code from set up installation wizard in my application

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, installation

I have created a Windows application for installing features (like SQL server silent installation, vlc and others) in batch where user can select which features to install. Now I want to detect if any of the installation is completed successfully or aborted or did not installed successfully. How can I catch this event in the windows application?
used the following code to launch each set up:

If chkVLC.Checked = True Then
            Process.Start("E:\Personal Projects\VS Works\Win App\testLastinstallation\testLastinstallation\testLastinstallation\Executables\vlc-1.1.7-win32-Tatilley.exe")
        End If

I tried to do same kind of thing using installationSheild wizard, which seemed very complex to me. That's why I created this windows application which i intend to use as custom action in installationSheild wizard Frown | :(

Can you guys give any solution/example?

Answer (score 0):

using `Process.ExitCode`, after `Process.HasExited`. ie: after `Loop While Not WaitForExit(1000)`

Like this : [MSDN - Process.ExitCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process.exitcode)

of course, process exit codes vary by application. some return -# for errors, some return #, some return -1/1, some return 0-# = success.

technically/usually 0 = no error.